# Formatear y remplazar valores en cadena de texto

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Soy algo nuevo utilizando Transact-sql y estoy realizando una consulta mediante la cual traigo una cadena de texto, dicha cadena debo formatearla siguiendo un esquema y rellenar con valores para que se cumpla con el formato:

Esta es la tabla que consulto y de la cual solo obtengo el documento de cada registro.

| id | documento |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8-550-780 |
| 2 | E-8-4512 |
| 3 | 8PI-485-87 |
| 4 | PE-87-480 |
| 5 | N-8-4512 |
| 6 | 9AV-18-2148 |

Utilizo el siguiente esquema para formatear

| Provincia | Inicial | Tomo | Asiento |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 posiciones | 2 posiciones | 5 posiciones | 6 posiciones |

Si el documento coincide con alguno de los campos del esquema la cadena resultante debe tener la longitud para cada campo y rellenar las demás posiciones con b a la izquierda (como un zfill de python).
Ejemplo:

| Documento | Provincia | Inicial | Tomo | Asiento | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 posiciones | 2 posiciones | 5 posiciones | 6 posiciones |  |
| 8-550-780 | 8 |  | 550 | 780 | b8bbbb550bbb780 |
| E-8-4512 |  | E | 8 | 4512 | bbEbbbbb8bb4512 |
| N-8-4512 |  | N | 8 | 4512 | bbNbbbbb8bb4512 |
| PE-87-480 |  | PE | 87 | 480 | bbPEbbb87bbb480 |
| 8PI-485-87 | 8 | PI | 485 | 87 | b8PIbb485bbbb87 |
| 9AV-18-2148 | 9 | AV | 18 | 2148 | b9AVbbb18bb2148 |

- Si la cadena empieza con un numero (ej. 8, 9, 7) corresponde a la Provincia
- Si la cadena empieza con una letra o luego de la provincia sigue una/s letras (ej. E, N, 8PI) corresponde a la Inicial
- Los siguientes valores de la cadena separados por el guion corresponden a Tomo y asiento (**87-480**, **550-780**)

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT documento, STRING_AGG(value, 'b')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT documento
    FROM usuario
) u
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(documemto, '-')
GROUP BY documento
```

STRING_SPLIT Me genera un columna `value` con cada valor resultante de hacer split:

| Documento | value |
| --- | --- |
| 8-550-780 | 8 |
| 8-550-780 | 550 |
| 8-550-780 | 780 |

Y STRING_AGG me concatena los valores agrupados por documento:

| Documento | value |
| --- | --- |
| 8-550-780 | 8b550b780 |

Pero no logro agregar la validación para registro del split, ni agregar la cantidad de posiciones según el esquema

Espero puedan guiarme, ya sea con una solución o alguna función que pueda emplear.

PD: Estoy analizando el uso de CASE WHEN, pero no se  como hacerlo.

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto requiere unos cuantos pasos para garantizar que queda bien. Esta solución usa una función nativa que permite dividir cadenas de texto. Sin embargo, esta función está diseñada para dividir nombres de objetos, por lo que la longitud está limitada y la cantidad de partes también. Afortunadamente, el requerimiento parece que se ajusta a los límites, solo tenemos que cambiar los guiones por puntos.

Es así como empezamos con los 2 primeros pasos: cambiar guiones por puntos y dividir usando `PARSENAME`.

```
CREATE TABLE Documentos(
    id          int,
    documento   varchar(20)
);
INSERT INTO Documentos
VALUES  ( 1, '8-550-780'),
        ( 2, 'E-8-4512'),
        ( 3, '8PI-485-87'),
        ( 4, 'PE-87-480'),
        ( 5, 'N-8-4512'),
        ( 6, '9AV-18-2148');

SELECT *
FROM Documentos d
CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE( documento, '-', '.')) d1(documento)
CROSS APPLY( SELECT PARSENAME( d1.documento,3) AS ProvinciaInicial,
                    PARSENAME( d1.documento,2) AS Tomo,
                    PARSENAME( d1.documento,1) AS Asiento) d2;
```

Una vez que tenemos las 3 columnas, podemos dividir la primera entre letras y números. Para obtener la posición de la primer letra usamos `PATINDEX`. Usé un patrón para identificar lo que no sea un número y no depender de que las mayúsculas, minúsculas o acentos generen problemas. En caso de que no haya letras, regresará un cero y ese cero lo hacemos nulo con `NULLIF` para después cambiarlo a 4 con `ISNULL`. Probablemente podría usar 2.

```
SELECT d.*,
    d3.Provincia,
    d3.Inicial,
    d2.Tomo,
    d2.Asiento
FROM Documentos d
CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE( documento, '-', '.')) d1(documento)
CROSS APPLY( SELECT PARSENAME( d1.documento,3) AS ProvinciaInicial,
                    PARSENAME( d1.documento,2) AS Tomo,
                    PARSENAME( d1.documento,1) AS Asiento) d2
CROSS APPLY( SELECT SUBSTRING( d2.ProvinciaInicial, 0, ISNULL( NULLIF( PATINDEX( '%[^0-9]%', d2.ProvinciaInicial), 0), 4)) AS Provincia,
                    SUBSTRING( d2.ProvinciaInicial, ISNULL( NULLIF( PATINDEX( '%[^0-9]%', d2.ProvinciaInicial), 0), 4), 4) AS Inicial) d3;
```

Ahora ya tenemos nuestras 4 columnas, lo único que falta es asignarle los lugares correspondientes y rellenar con `b`. Para eso podemos usar REPLICATE y LEN para definir cuantas veces debe aparecer la `b` o simplemente hacer una cadena larga para después cortarla con `LEFT` y `RIGHT`. Y todo lo concatenamos al final.

```
SELECT d.*,
    -- Opción 1
    CONCAT(
        REPLICATE( 'b', 2 - LEN(d3.Provincia)),
        d3.Provincia,
        d3.Inicial,
        REPLICATE( 'b', 2 - LEN(d3.Inicial)),
        REPLICATE( 'b', 5 - LEN(d2.Tomo)),
        d2.Tomo,
        REPLICATE( 'b', 6 - LEN(d2.Asiento)),
        d2.Asiento),
    -- Opción 2
    CONCAT(
        RIGHT( 'bb' + d3.Provincia, 2),
        LEFT( d3.Inicial + 'bb', 2),
        RIGHT( 'bbbbb' + d2.Tomo, 5),
        RIGHT( 'bbbbbb' + d2.Asiento, 6))
FROM Documentos d
CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE( documento, '-', '.')) d1(documento)
CROSS APPLY( SELECT PARSENAME( d1.documento,3) AS ProvinciaInicial,
                    PARSENAME( d1.documento,2) AS Tomo,
                    PARSENAME( d1.documento,1) AS Asiento) d2
CROSS APPLY( SELECT SUBSTRING( d2.ProvinciaInicial, 0, ISNULL( NULLIF( PATINDEX( '%[^0-9]%', d2.ProvinciaInicial), 0), 4)) AS Provincia,
                    SUBSTRING( d2.ProvinciaInicial, ISNULL( NULLIF( PATINDEX( '%[^0-9]%', d2.ProvinciaInicial), 0), 4), 4) AS Inicial) d3;
```

Comment: Que nivel. Excelente tu respuesta y de gran ayuda. Muchas gracias!