# Aplicar CROSS APPLY y llenar columna si los datos de otra columna coincide con el patron RegEx

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

La problemática es la siguiente:
Soy algo nuevo utilizando T-SQL y tengo un requerimiento en el cual tengo que dividir una cadena cuyo separador es un guion para obtener cada una de las posiciones resultantes y asignarlo a otras columnas, aplicar dicha division solo a aquellas columnas que coincidan con el patron RegEx y colocar en otra columna indicando si coinciden o no:

La tabla es la siguiente

| Identificador |
| --- |
| 81802-23-15987 |
| 8-550-780 |
| 13-NT-1234-12345 |
| 123456789-1-2014 |
| 389455-1-422729 D.V.12 |
| 40979 25 281810 DV99 |
| 8NT-1-12341 |
| 20601249678 |
| 1-24324234 |

En donde los patrones pueden ser los siguientes:

- **[de 1 a 7 digitos]**-**[de 1 a 7 digitos]**-**[de 1 a 7 digitos]** -> Coincide con 81802-23-15987 y 8-550-780
- **[de 1 a 2 digitos]-[Letra=NT]-[de 1 a 5 posiciones]-[de 1 a 6 posiciones]** -> Coincide con 13-NT-1234-12345
- **[de 1 a 9 digitos]-[1 digito]-[4 digitos Entre 2014 y 2023]** -> Coincide con 123456789-1-2014

Estos registros deben llevar en la columna Match la letra T y aquellos que no coinciden la letra F

Y el resultado a obtener debe ser el siguiente:

| Identificador | Match | pos1 | pos2 | pos3 | pos4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 81802-23-15987 | T | 81802 | 23 | 15987 |  |
| 8-550-780 | T | 8 | 550 | 780 |  |
| 13-NT-1234-12345 | T | 13 | NT | 1234 | 12345 |
| 123456789-1-2014 | T | 123456789 | 1 | 2014 |  |
| 389455-1-422729 D.V.12 | F |  |  |  |  |
| 40979 25 281810 DV99 | F |  |  |  |  |
| 8NT-1-12341 | F |  |  |  |  |
| 20601249678 | F |  |  |  |  |
| 1-24324234 | F |  |  |  |  |

De momento he intendo lo siguiente:

Con esta query solo logro hacer la distinción excluyendo dichos registro, y de igual manera me tocaria agregar un sin fin de patrones:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE Identificador LIKE '[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%[-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%[-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
        OR Identificador LIKE '[0-9][0-9]%[-][NT][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%[-][0-9]%'
        OR Identificaro LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%[-][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

En esta consulta aplico un cross apply e intento validar mediante CASE la coincidencia

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN -- He Aquí donde he de colocar la validación de lo patrones pero tendría que hacer muchos WHEN y quizas exista una forma mas optima de hacerlo
    END pos1
    CASE
        WHEN -- He Aqui donde he de colocar la validacion de lo patrones y retornar T o F segun la coincidencia
    END Match
FROM record r
CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE(r.Identificador, '-', '.')) ca1(id)
CROSS APPLY( PARSENAME(ca1.id, 4) AS pos4,
             PARSENAME(ca1.id, 3) AS pos3,
             PARSENAME(ca1.id, 2) AS pos2,
             PARSENAME(ca1.id, 1) AS pos1
)
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme, alguna solución, referencia a algún link o funciones que puedan ayudarme a resolverlo.

Comment: ¿Es parte del requerimiento utilizar `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: @Marcos Seguramente viene de la solución que le di acá https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/586453/formatear-y-remplazar-valores-en-cadena-de-texto

Comment: Si quiseras poder usar Expresiones Regulares para evitar tener que crear _"un sin fin de patrones"_, te recomiendo [leer esto](http://web.archive.org/web/20160307210334/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx)

Comment: En efecto, estoy haciendo uso de una implementacion con la que me colaboro @LuisCazares en una pregunta anterior, pero con la variante que tengo que validar que el campo coincida con el patron para poder aplicar el cross apply (o mejor dicho aplicar el proceso dentro del cross apply), sin excluir (WHERE) ningun registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo el patrón de la respuesta que ya te han dado en el otro hilo, por tanto no es necesario aclarar como funciona `Parsename`

El primer cambio que tienes que hacer es que la fila de valor `13-NT-1234-12345` tiene un comportamiento un poco diferente al resto, al tener 4 partes, y por tanto la tratamos evaluando la existencia o no de todas las partes.

Luego metemos todo en una tabla derivada, porque la solución es más fácil de seguir.

*Nota: He usado una variable de tipo tabla por facilidad. El uso es idéntico a usar una tabla. Donde dice Declare @record Table, si hubiera sido Create table record, sería lo mismo.*

```
Declare @record Table (identificador varchar(100))
Insert into @record (identificador)
values
('81802-23-15987'),
('8-550-780'),
('13-NT-1234-12345'),
('123456789-1-2014'),
('389455-1-422729 D.V.12'),
('40979 25 281810 DV99'),
('8NT-1-12341'),
('20601249678'),
('1-24324234')

SELECT DATA.identificador,
       DATA.pos1,
       DATA.pos2,
       DATA.pos3,
       DATA.pos4 
    FROM(
    SELECT d.identificador, 
        case when d2.pos4 is null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos4 end as pos1,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos2 end as pos2,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos2 else d2.pos3 end as pos3,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos3 else d2.pos4 end as pos4
    FROM @record d
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE( identificador, '-', '.')) d1(documento)
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT PARSENAME( d1.documento,3) AS pos1,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,2) AS pos2,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,1) AS pos3,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,4) AS pos4
                        ) d2
) AS DATA
```

[image: Res1a]

A partir de esto, evaluamos cada solicitud por partes.

**Caso 1**

Dice de 1 a 7 dígitos en las 3 partes.
Podemos hacerlo buscando si contiene algún número y no contiene caracteres diferentes de números y la longitud de la cadena está entre 1 y 7.

```
SELECT DATA.identificador,
      
    CASE WHEN 
        ( -- CASO 1
            DATA.POS1 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
        AND DATA.POS1 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
        AND LEN(DATA.POS1) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
        AND DATA.POS2 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
        AND DATA.POS2 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
        AND LEN(DATA.POS2) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
        AND DATA.POS3 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
        AND DATA.POS3 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
        AND LEN(DATA.POS3) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
        ) -- CONTIENE SOLO NÚMEROS
        then 'OK' ELSE 'NO OK' 
    END AS MATCH,
       DATA.pos1,
       DATA.pos2,
       DATA.pos3,
       DATA.pos4 
    FROM(
    SELECT d.identificador, 
        case when d2.pos4 is null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos4 end as pos1,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos2 end as pos2,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos2 else d2.pos3 end as pos3,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos3 else d2.pos4 end as pos4
    FROM @record d
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE( identificador, '-', '.')) d1(documento)
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT PARSENAME( d1.documento,3) AS pos1,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,2) AS pos2,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,1) AS pos3,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,4) AS pos4
                        ) d2
) AS DATA
```

[image: res1b]

**Caso 2**

Que para la posición 1 tenga un caracter del rango númerico o que sean dos caracteres del rango númerico. Además la posición dos tiene que ser explicitamente NT, y para la posición 3 y 4 miramos su longitud.

```
SELECT DATA.identificador,
      
    CASE WHEN 
        ( -- CASO 2
            (DATA.POS1 LIKE '[0-9]' OR DATA.POS1 LIKE '[0-9][0-9]') --1 A 2 DIGITOS
            AND DATA.POS2 = 'NT'  -- LETRAS NT
            AND LEN(DATA.POS3) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 -- DE 1 A 5 POSICIONES
            AND LEN(DATA.POS4) BETWEEN 1 AND 6 -- DE 1 A 6 POSICIONES,
        ) 
        then 'OK' ELSE 'NO OK' 
    END AS MATCH,
       DATA.pos1,
       DATA.pos2,
       DATA.pos3,
       DATA.pos4 
    FROM(
    SELECT d.identificador, 
        case when d2.pos4 is null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos4 end as pos1,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos2 end as pos2,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos2 else d2.pos3 end as pos3,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos3 else d2.pos4 end as pos4
    FROM @record d
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE( identificador, '-', '.')) d1(documento)
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT PARSENAME( d1.documento,3) AS pos1,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,2) AS pos2,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,1) AS pos3,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,4) AS pos4
                        ) d2
) AS DATA
```

[image: Res]

**Caso 3**

Igual que en los casos anteriores, extraemos los números (si son o no) y además miramos la longitud de la posición 1 y 2 y que la posición 3 contenga un valor entre los que solicitamos.

```
SELECT DATA.identificador,
      
    CASE WHEN 
        ( -- CASO 3
                DATA.POS1 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
            AND DATA.POS1 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
            AND LEN(DATA.POS1) BETWEEN 1 AND 9 -- CONTIENE SOLO NÚMEROS
            AND LEN(DATA.POS2) = 1 
            AND DATA.POS3 BETWEEN 2014 AND 2023
        ) 
        then 'OK' ELSE 'NO OK' 
    END AS MATCH,
       DATA.pos1,
       DATA.pos2,
       DATA.pos3,
       DATA.pos4 
    FROM(
    SELECT d.identificador, 
        case when d2.pos4 is null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos4 end as pos1,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos2 end as pos2,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos2 else d2.pos3 end as pos3,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos3 else d2.pos4 end as pos4
    FROM @record d
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE( identificador, '-', '.')) d1(documento)
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT PARSENAME( d1.documento,3) AS pos1,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,2) AS pos2,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,1) AS pos3,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,4) AS pos4
                        ) d2
) AS DATA
```

[image: Res3]

**Resultado**

Todo junto, es simplemente añadir un or a cada condición.

```
Declare @record Table (identificador varchar(100))
Insert into @record (identificador)
values
('81802-23-15987'),
('8-550-780'),
('13-NT-1234-12345'),
('123456789-1-2014'),
('389455-1-422729 D.V.12'),
('40979 25 281810 DV99'),
('8NT-1-12341'),
('20601249678'),
('1-24324234')

SELECT DATA.identificador,
      
    CASE WHEN 
        ( -- CASO 1
                DATA.POS1 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
            AND DATA.POS1 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
            AND LEN(DATA.POS1) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
            AND DATA.POS2 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
            AND DATA.POS2 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
            AND LEN(DATA.POS2) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
            AND DATA.POS3 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
            AND DATA.POS3 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
            AND LEN(DATA.POS3) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
        ) 
        OR 
        ( -- CASO 2
            (DATA.POS1 LIKE '[0-9]' OR DATA.POS1 LIKE '[0-9][0-9]') --1 A 2 DIGITOS
            AND DATA.POS2 = 'NT'  -- LETRAS NT
            AND LEN(DATA.POS3) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 -- DE 1 A 5 POSICIONES
            AND LEN(DATA.POS4) BETWEEN 1 AND 6 -- DE 1 A 6 POSICIONES,
        )
        OR 
        ( -- CASO 3
                DATA.POS1 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
            AND DATA.POS1 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
            AND LEN(DATA.POS1) BETWEEN 1 AND 9 -- CONTIENE SOLO NÚMEROS
            AND LEN(DATA.POS2) = 1 
            AND DATA.POS3 BETWEEN 2014 AND 2023
        )
        THEN 'T' 
        ELSE 'F' 
    END AS MATCH,
       DATA.pos1,
       DATA.pos2,
       DATA.pos3,
       DATA.pos4 
    FROM(
    SELECT d.identificador, 
        case when d2.pos4 is null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos4 end as pos1,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos2 end as pos2,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos2 else d2.pos3 end as pos3,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos3 else d2.pos4 end as pos4
    FROM @record d
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE( identificador, '-', '.')) d1(documento)
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT PARSENAME( d1.documento,3) AS pos1,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,2) AS pos2,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,1) AS pos3,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,4) AS pos4
                        ) d2
) AS DATA
```

[image: Res]

Mejoras. Pero esto es un poco feo y repetir esto en algunas consultas no es nada grato. Pero podemos encapsular todo este código en funciones.

**Function**

Una vez que tienes ya verificado que la validación es la que necesitas, encapsulas el código en una función.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.validateColumns
(@pos1 varchar(10), 
 @pos2 varchar(10),
 @pos3 varchar(10),
 @pos4 varchar(10)
 )
 returns VarChar(1)
 As
 Begin
 return (
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 
            ( -- CASO 1
                    @POS1 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
                AND @POS1 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
                AND LEN(@POS1) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
                AND @POS2 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
                AND @POS2 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
                AND LEN(@POS2) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
                AND @POS3 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
                AND @POS3 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
                AND LEN(@POS3) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
        ) 
            OR 
            ( -- CASO 2
                (@POS1 LIKE '[0-9]' OR @POS1 LIKE '[0-9][0-9]') --1 A 2 DIGITOS
                AND @POS2 = 'NT'  -- LETRAS NT
                AND LEN(@POS3) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 -- DE 1 A 5 POSICIONES
                AND LEN(@POS4) BETWEEN 1 AND 6 -- DE 1 A 6 POSICIONES,
            )
            OR 
            ( -- CASO 3
                    @POS1 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
                AND @POS1 NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%' 
                AND LEN(@POS1) BETWEEN 1 AND 9 -- CONTIENE SOLO NÚMEROS
                AND LEN(@POS2) = 1 
                AND @POS3 BETWEEN 2014 AND 2023
            )
            THEN 'T' 
            ELSE 'F' end as result
    );
 End
```

Ahora para llamarla, solo tienes que poner su nombre y los parámetros.

```
SELECT DATA.identificador,
        dbo.validateColumns(data.pos1, data.pos2, data.pos3, data.pos4) As Match,
       DATA.pos1,
       DATA.pos2,
       DATA.pos3,
       DATA.pos4 
    FROM(
    SELECT d.identificador, 
        case when d2.pos4 is null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos4 end as pos1,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos1 else d2.pos2 end as pos2,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos2 else d2.pos3 end as pos3,
        case when d2.pos4 is not null then d2.pos3 else d2.pos4 end as pos4
    FROM @record d
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT REPLACE( identificador, '-', '.')) d1(documento)
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT PARSENAME( d1.documento,3) AS pos1,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,2) AS pos2,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,1) AS pos3,
                        PARSENAME( d1.documento,4) AS pos4
                        ) d2
) AS DATA
```

[image: Res7]

Claro que también podrías hacer lo mismo, y pasar solo el identificador y que te devolviera todas las columnas encapsulando el código en una función table-inline, pero eso queda fuera de la pregunta.

Comment: Grande Maestro, en lo que me llegaba alguna respuesta iba por el mismo camino (LIKE '%pattern%' y tenia la duda con ciertos patrones que has resuelto claramente en tu respuesta. Muchas gracias @JaviFer2